# Replace unknown value in SQL query with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I use SQL/PostgreSQL to do something like this (psuedo code):

```
UPDATE table
SET content = replace(content, 'padding-top: $VAR', 'padding-top: 30px')
WHERE user = 1;
```

The $VAR is an unknown value, like 80%, 50% or 80px. How could I do this?

Comment: Is this query inside a backend (e.g. PHP) script?

Comment: No, I intend to use it directly against the PostgreSQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `regexp_replace`:

```
UPDATE table
SET content = regexp_replace(content, '^padding-top: .*$', 'padding-top: 30px')
WHERE user = 1;
```

Note that as its name suggests, `regexp_replace` takes a regular expression. So I am using `^`, `$` for the beginning and the end, and `.*` which means "match with any sequence of characters" (`.` means "match with any character" and `*` means "match the previous symbol as many times as possible").

Comment: Nice, what does `.*` mean. I know `^` is the beginning and the `$` the end. But what about the dot and the astrix?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.